# i need to create an alarm in cloudwatch using CFT but i'm getting FAILED TO RETREIVE EXTERNAL VALUES. yaml syntax is correct checked by yamllint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
CPUAlarm:
Description: High CPU Utilization
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
Resources:
CPUUtilizationAlarm:
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
Properties:
AlarmDescription: Rebooting the instance after reaching the maximum CPU utilization.
Namespace: AWS/EC2
MetricName: CPUUtilization
Statistic: Average
Period: '60'
EvaluationPeriods: '3'
ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
Threshold: '90'
AlarmActions: 'arn:aws:automate:ap-south-1:i-0db3310c5ec72d8db:reboot'
Dimensions:
- Name: 'i-0db3310c5ec72d8db'

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: Template format error: Unrecognized parameter type: arn:aws:ec2::ap-south-1::i-0db3310c5ec72d8db

Answer (score 1):

There is no such type as:

```
Type: arn:aws:ec2::ap-south-1::i-0db3310c5ec72d8db
```

Maybe you wanted the following:

```
  CPUAlarm:
    Description: High CPU Utilization
    Type: String
    Default: arn:aws:ec2::ap-south-1::i-0db3310c5ec72d8db
```

Comment: @GauravRaj This is correct. If it did not work, you have further issues in your template.